# I have a tracking script that runs on an interstitial redirect page. How do I know the script had enough time to execute before the redirect?

Tags: javascript

The following is the body of the interstitial page, used just for conversion tracking. My question is: Since the first script is injecting another script, do I risk redirecting before the first script has fully executed?

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
var OB_ADV_ID=xxxx;
var scheme = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
var str = '<script src="'+scheme+'widgets.outbrain.com/obtp.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>';
document.write(str);
</script>

<script>
window.location.replace("{{link}}")
</script>
```

Comment: well, what happens when you run the code?

Comment: no: the first script will connect and completely load and execute before the redirect.

Comment: Did you get any more clarity on this?

Answer (score -1):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to do with your code, but it looks like what you want to do is create a callback for the response of the tracking code. Or personally, I would have the tracking logic on the landing page.